# Laravel @extends() pointer system

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.7.

If I navigate to a page that does not exist, I get 404 error page handling.

That view is located in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Views/404.blade.php`

However this file extends:

```
@extends('errors::illustrated-layout')
```

This is located in the same folder, and is named `illustrated-layout.blade.php`

So I guess that the `errors::` part points to the specific folder., e.g. `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Views/`

**Question:** Is this type of pointer something that could be created manually, so a person wouldn't have to write the entire path to a specific folder, when extending a view? Would make things much more clean.

Comment: I don't understand very well your question, but if you want to custom  404 page error, you can do that, u want to custom 404 page content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a view namespace and achieve the same result.

For example, you can add the following in `AppServiceProvider@boot`:

```
$this->app['view']->addNamespace('admin', base_path() . '/resources/views/admin');
```

and let's suppose you have a blade file in `resources/views/admin/layouts/master.blade.php`

you can access it with `admin::layouts.master`